# Find if element is included in array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array `A = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6]` and I want to check if a couple of values, let's say `B = [1 2]` is included in `A`. How would you do that?

I tried using `C = ismember(B, A)` but it gives as a result `[1 1]` both for `[1 2]` and `[1 3]`.

Comment: Try doing `C = ismember(A, B)`, If you want to check whole row, use 'rows'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

`C = ismember(A,B,'rows');`